# First attempt to copy in excel results in error message "Cannot open the clipboard"

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, clipboard

I am running Office Home and Student 2013. In Excel, after I open a file or start a new spreadsheet, the first time I try to copy a cell or a range of cells, I get the error message "Cannot open the clipboard".

After I press Enter or Esc to clear the error, subsequent copies work fine, until I quit Excel and try again. If I open a second file in the same session Copy works fine the first time on that file. Only if I quit Excel will it happen again.

I can also click on a cell and copy the data from the data entry bar, that always works. But regardless of whether I've done that or not, the first Copy of a cell still fails.

This error does not happen in any of the other Office programs, it seems to be unique to copying a cell.

I have tried the suggestions I found by searching for this error. I have tried all relevant things I found in my searches. Here's what I have tried:

-Start Excel in Safe mode

-Repair Office

-Reinstall Office

-Disable services (disabling Google services fixed it for a little while)

-Try a different account

-Disable antivirus & firewall

-Keeping the Excel Clipboard open fixes it in most but not all sessions.

-Never quitting Excel - that way only the very first Copy fails

Any other ideas?

Comment: The original title makes no sense and dosen't have anything to do with the question... clipboard betraying you? :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yep, and thanks for correcting my idiocy!

Comment: I'm more curious to the... why. Its an interesting question otherwise.

Comment: I'd looked up a wine just before, and forgot to press Ctrl-C when I started the question. Just goes to show: *always* check your work!

Comment: It is likely that other software is occupying the clipboard.

Comment: @Ceasar Quite possibly, but why only the first time I copy, and every time Excel is started? How would that first copy silence the other app until Excel is restarted?